# Left join in Hibernate on the same entity and having other conditions

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to do some performance fixes on java project with Hibernate 3.3.2 (upgrade not possible). There's an inner query - a not in condition. During a simplification process, I want to rewrite it as a left outer join. But I am struggling with HQL syntax. I googled a lot, tried many attempts, read the [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html), but I utterly failed.

```
public class Document implements {
    Long recordId, documentId;
    String status;

public class Data {
    Long dataId;
```

Original HQL:

```
from Document ln where ln.status = 'Active' and ln.recordId not in 
(select ln.recordId from Document ln, Data cd where ln.status = 'Active' and ln.documentId = cd.dataId))
```

My last revision, that fails on the syntax error:

```
select ln from Document as ln 
left join Document.recordId as lne with lne.status='Active' 
left join Data as cd with lne.documentId=cd.dataId 
where ln.loanDocumentStatus='Active' and lne.recordId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```java
String hql = 
    "select ln " +
    "from Document ln " +
    "left join Data cd on ln.documentId = cd.dataId and ln.status = 'Active' " +
    "where ln.status = 'Active' and cd.dataId is null";

List<Document> documents = session.createQuery(hql).list();
```

Comment: Interesting idea to remove one join. We tried but it fails with "unexpected token: on near line 1, column 93" which is "on".